# Does Redhat subscript provide access to yum repositories?

Tags: rhel, yum

I created an install script on an AWS Redhat instance and i'm not trying to use the same script on a base Redhat install.  Nearly every package in my script comes back as "No package..."  I've expanded my local repos but i've still haven't been able to match the repos I had access to in AWS.  Could this be because I do not have a Redhat subscription and access to the Redhat subscription channels?

My experience in Redhat has been limited by always using Amazon Web Services, so I haven't had to deal with a clean install in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Red Hat subscription just provides access to system updates, you should already have access to the software itself (you just don't get the updates). If you installed from DVD, there should be a yum repo on there that will enable you to install packages from the installation DVD.

If you mounted the DVD it `/tmp/mnt` you can create the following yum repo in `/etc/yum.repos.d/`:

```
[rhel-dvd]
name=RHEL Installation DVD
baseurl=file:///tmp/mnt/Server/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///tmp/mnt/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release
```

Obviously, change `/tmp/mnt` to wherever you mounted the actual installation disc.

That said, if you don't get system updates, you're probably better off just using the analogous version of CentOS (CentOS 5 is RHEL5, CentOS 6 is RHEL 6, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Red Hat subscriptions typically make use of another tool called `up2date` which updates the systems against separate repositories. I believe you can mix a RHEL system so that it makes use of both this mechanism as well as using YUM repositories but the same care needs to be taken to not mix them too much or you'll leave to dependency hell.

Incidentally Red Hat covers this here in the documentation, both in the use of YUM, setting it up to co-exist with `up2date`, and the implications.

- [What is yum and how to use it?](https://access.redhat.com/site/solutions/9934)

Comment: Starting with RHEL5, regular system updates are provided via a `yum` plugin which looks to the end user like a yum repo (even though it technically isn't). `up2date` is used on RHEL4 and earlier.

Comment: @JoelDavis - Thanks for clarification. I seem to remember using `up2date` on RHEL5 too.

Comment: For whatever reason, Red Hat kept referencing `up2date` with their yum plugin (for example `/etc/sysconfig/rhn/up2date`) but the tool itself is gone and can't be installed. There are just a few weird artifacts with that tool's name in it [here and there](https://dpaste.de/4f3A).